# I want to display my nested JSON data into recylerview using adapter and model class

Tags: android, json

Please focus on adapter because I want a suggestion on how to display data in the adapter.

user.json

```
{
  "UserDetails":
  [
    {
      "firstName" : "KP",
      "lastName" : "xyz",
      "location" : "GOA",
      "websites" : [
        {
          "description" : "work",
          "URL" : "digitalocean"
        },
        {
          "description" : "tutorials",
          "URL" : "digitalocean/community/tutorials"
        }
      ],
      "socialMedia" : [
        {
          "description" : "twitter",
          "link" : "twitter/digitalocean"
        },
        {
          "description" : "facebook",
          "link" : "facebook/DigitalOceanCloudHosting"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName" : "NP",
      "lastName" : "ABC",
      "location" : "Shimla",
      "websites" : [
        {
          "description" : "work",
          "URL" : "digitalocean"
        },
        {
          "description" : "tutorials",
          "URL" : "digitalocean/community/tutorials"
        }
      ],
      "socialMedia" : [
        {
          "description" : "twitter",
          "link" : "twitter/digitalocean"
        },
        {
          "description" : "facebook",
          "link" : "facebook/DigitalOceanCloudHosting"
        },
        {
          "description" : "github",
          "link" : "github/digitalocean"
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
private void prepareMovieData() {

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

        JSONArray mUserDetailsArray = obj.getJSONArray("UserDetails");

        for (int i = 0; i < mUserDetailsArray.length(); i++) {
            User user = new User();
            JSONObject jo_inside = mUserDetailsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            user.setFirst_name(jo_inside.getString("firstName"));
            user.setLast_name(jo_inside.getString("lastName"));
            user.setLocation(jo_inside.getString("location"));
            Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("firstName"));

            JSONArray mWebsitesArray = jo_inside.getJSONArray("websites");
            Log.d("Details mWebsites-->", String.valueOf(jo_inside.getJSONArray("websites")));
            for (int j = 0; j < mWebsitesArray.length(); j++) {
                Websites websites = new Websites();
                JSONObject challengeObject = mWebsitesArray.getJSONObject(j);
                websites.setDescription(challengeObject.getString("description"));
                websites.setURL(challengeObject.getString("URL"));
                user.getWebsites().add(websites);
            }

            userList.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("Error-->", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

MovieAdapter.java

```java
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title1, year1, genre1, txtDescription1, txtUrl1, txtDescription2, txtUrl2;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
            genre1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtgenre);
            year1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtyear);
            txtDescription1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription1);
            txtUrl1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl1);
            txtDescription2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription2);
            txtUrl2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl2);
        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<User> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.demo_movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        User user = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title1.setText(user.getFirst_name());
        holder.genre1.setText(user.getLast_name());
        holder.year1.setText(user.getLocation());
        holder.txtDescription1.setText(user.getWebsites().get(0).getDescription());
        holder.txtUrl1.setText(user.getWebsites().get(0).getURL());
        holder.txtDescription2.setText(user.getWebsites().get(1).getDescription());
        holder.txtUrl2.setText(user.getWebsites().get(1).getURL());

    }
}
```

Comment: What type of error or issue are you facing? Your adapter class looks alright.

Comment: adapter is alright but look JSON file how i can display websites data to user because it may possible that some user has more than 3 website and some has only one at that time how i can display those data?

Comment: You can take `RecyclerView` inside particular `itemView` of `RecyclerView`. I would not say that it's not possible but you would have to do some extra efforts to achieve smoothness for nested `RecyclerViews` *(I.e. use of `RecyclerViewPool`)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all the `txtUrl` with a single `LinearLayout` (Vertical) and loop through the website list to add a single `TextView` for each website. This will ensure your view will adopt any number of dynamic websites.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
    User user = moviesList.get(position);
            
    for (Websites website in user.getWebsites()) {
        TextView txtUrl = new TextView(context);
        txtUrl.setText(website.getURL());
        holder.layoutUrls.addView(txtUrl);
    }
}
```